# SwiftUI Form with multiple expandable Lists has no show/collapse animation(GIF)

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, uikit

I have a `Form` with `Sections`. Each section has its own `List` that can show/collapse additional rows. The problem is if I embed the `List` in the `Form` the collapsing/showing animation does not work anymore. Any ideas how to fix the animation?

```
struct MyForm: View {
var items = [MyItem(text: "A"), MyItem(text: "B"), MyItem(text: "C"), MyItem(text: "D"), MyItem(text: "E"), MyItem(text: "F"), MyItem(text: "G"), MyItem(text: "H"), MyItem(text: "I")]

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Sector")) {
                    ExpandableList(items: items, visible: 4)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Region")) {
                    ExpandableList(items: items, visible: 4)
                }
            }.navigationTitle(Text("Filter"))
        }
    }
}


struct MyItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let text: String
}

struct ExpandableList: View {
    private var items: [MyItem]
    private var visible: Int
    private var visibleItems: [MyItem]

    @State var isExpanded = false

    init(items: [MyItem], visible: Int) {
        self.items = items
        self.visible = visible
    
        if visible < items.count {
            self.visibleItems = Array(items[0..<visible])
        } else {
            self.visibleItems = items
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
    
        List {
            ForEach(isExpanded ? items : visibleItems) { item in
                Text(item.text)
            }
        
            HStack {
                Button {
                    isExpanded.toggle()
                } label: {
                    if isExpanded {
                        Label("Show less", systemImage: "arrow.up")
                    } else {
                        Label("Show all", systemImage: "arrow.down")
                    }
                }
            }
        }.animation(.easeOut, value: isExpanded)
    }
}
```

[image: Good]
[image: Bad]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works by using `withAnimation` directly when setting the property in your button.

```
    List {
        ForEach(isExpanded ? items : visibleItems) { item in
            Text(item.text)
        }
    
        HStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation{       // <-- HERE!!
                    isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                if isExpanded {
                    Label("Show less", systemImage: "arrow.up")
                } else {
                    Label("Show all", systemImage: "arrow.down")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //.animation(.easeOut, value: isExpanded)
```